# IOS 7.1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Cordova AdMod Plug-in on Phone

Tags: ios, cordova, admob, phonegap-plugins, ios7.1

i've write phonegap based ios application. and using this plug-in

```
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob
```

for admob. Everything is fine on ios simulator but if try in iphone(iOS 7.1) i've got an error:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Plug-in line - (void)createBannerView:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
```

how to solve this problem ?

image : [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check [this post](http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/) (issue #1)

It suggests replacing these two files in **platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes**

[CDVCommandQueue.m](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ios.git;a=blob_plain;f=CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCommandQueue.m;h=1eddfe37ee699289701cd4caaf68486607010501;hb=82ce4f2) and 
[CDVViewController.m](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ios.git;a=blob_plain;f=CordovaLib/Classes/CDVViewController.m;h=7bda2cc4a70dad895f452b02fde673b1884ed7d3;hb=82ce4f2)

If it doesn't help (it didn't help me tdh) open up CDVCommandQueue.m, go to line 196-197 and edit the file like this:

[image]